# Is there a need to reaffirm a websocket connection?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a web application that relies on updated information from a server.  In the past, the client would send an ajax request 1000ms after the completion of the previous.  It worked well, but wasted resources.  The app has been converted to use a websocket when the client supports it (and degrade to Ajax when it doesn't).

In the past, ajax provided a pulse by indicating the browser was refreshing activity every second.  Now, it looks dead and just sits there working. I have the following:

```
function connect() {
    $("#text1").text('Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (connecting)');
    socket.onopen = function(){
        $("#text1").text('Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (open)');
    }
    socket.onmessage = function(msg){ checkDATA(msg.data); }
    socket.onclose = function(){ 
        $("#text1").text('Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (close)');
        setTimeout(function () { connect(); },500);
    }
    socket.onerror = function(){ 
        $("#text1").text('Socket Status: '+socket.readyState+' (error) '+msg.data);
    }
}
```

So I do have some indication of the status, but nothing that shows a pulse.  Should I just fake a pulse or is there something different/better that can/should be done to assure the connection is working?

Answer (score 1):

Underneath, a websocket is just a TCP socket.  So, first you should monitor all possible error conditions and socket notifications.  Then, second if you want to conclusively know that the socket is still alive, you will have to sent a regular piece of data and look for a server response.

You should note that on battery powered devices (phones, tablets, laptops), a regular network heartbeat can be a significant drain on the battery unless there are long time durations between heartbeats.

Another alternative would be to implement very smart error handling for sending and some sort of intelligent detection for received data.  For sending, if you send some data and find you get an error because the socket appears to be inoperable, then you could autoamtically tear down the connection and create a new one and try sending the data again.  The one gotcha with this is you have to code carefully to avoid any sort of loop where you get an error, recreate the socket, get an error, recreate the socket, over and over again.  Typically, you would retry only a small number of times (2-3) and space out the time between successive retries.

For receiving, if you are expecting to get an update from the server every so often (say at least every 15 minutes) and more than amount of time has elapsed since the last update, then you may want to test your existing connection to see if it is still live.

Using this type of technique has the advantage that when things are working properly, you don't use any more transmission/battery than necessary, but you still have some trouble detection/handling schemes in place to automatically detect when the connection might be in trouble and to restore it automatically.

Comment: What error(s) am I not monitoring?  I have this function wrapped in `try{} catch{}`, catch fires when the server reboots.  `Catch` waits 5 seconds and attempts ro reconnect.  I removed the reconnection `onerror`, because I was doubling the connection count with the server everytime there was an error.  Testing the connection seems avoidable, if I understood why/how the browser changes the connection status.